# Covariance, contravariance, and an ILookup-style interface

Tags: .net, generics, covariance, contravariance

If one is designing an interface like `ILookup` (for simplicity, assume it's simply `ICheckIfContained`, so the type of the item's value wouldn't matter), what would be the ideal type of variance with respect to the first parameter?

Checking to see if an `ICheckIfContained<Animal>` contains a particular `Cat` would be a natural operation, and would be type-safe under normal rules of contravariance.

Checking to see if an `ICheckIfContained<Cat>` contains a particular `Animal` would not be type-safe under normal rules of contravariance, but would be natural and well-defined (if the `Animal` in question is not a `Cat`, the proper behavior would be for the `ICheckIfContained` to say it does not contain the animal in question).

Checking to see if an `ICheckIfContained<Cat>` contains a particular `Dog` would not be particularly useful (the answer would always be "no") but the answer would be well-defined.  Note that the answer in this scenario, unlike the previous one, could be determined statically.

One approach would be to have an `ICheckIfContained` be a non-generic interface, and simply accept a parameter of type `Object`.  This would seem rather inefficient, however, in cases where the list contained nothing but a single type of struct.  On the other hand, if it's a generic interface, then the compiler would be unable to allow its use in the covariant scenario (passing in a parameter whose declared type is a parent of the expected type, such that the passed-in object might or might not be of the expected type).

Is there any nice pattern for getting the efficiency of generics in cases where the compiler can confirm that everything is the same type, while still allowing the general-case behavior of checking for whether an object of parent type is in the collection of child type?

Comment: With that kind of rep, I'd expect you to know how to format code in a question. Learn to use the back tick `.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I knew that the `backtick` worked in comments, but it didn't dawn on me to think it might also work in questions/answers, given that questions use HTML (like <B>) for things like *bold* that, in answers, are handled with punctuation marks (asterisks, in the case of bold).  I thought in questions/answers one was supposed to use something like <TT>, although the TT tag in particular doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can do that. It would definitely be efficient to be able to statically check this to false, but passing `Dog` to `Contains(cat)` can be optimized only if compiler knows exactly what kind of operation is performed by this method.

What if your `Contains` is actually `Add`? Compiler does not understand method names.

Comment: The idea with "Contains" is that it may be legitimately invoked with any type, whereas something like "Add" could not.  The situation is somewhat like the one with Object.Equals/IComparable<T>.Equals, except that an ICheckIfContained<T> would often use a function for comparing two distinct objects, a slightly different scenario from comparing an object to itself.

Comment: Yes, so how would you specify to compiler it should statically return `false` when types do not match? I understand the idea, but the compiler does not.

Comment: As a simple example, if one could overload generics based upon class or struct constraints, and ICheckIfContained<T> contained open generic methods `Contains<U>(U thing) where U:struct` and `Contains<U>(U thing) where U:class` methods, an implementation where T was a class could have its implementation of `Contains<U>(U thing) where U:struct` always return False.  If one could constrain a generic type to be a class *other than Object*, one could do likewise for implementations where T was a struct.

Comment: I recognize the necessity of boxing in the absence of generics; given that generics exist, I find boxing to be somewhat dubious (a generic Holder<T> class could be used in situations where one needed to store a struct in an object which expected a class type).  There are some cases where it would be helpful for a method like String.Format to accept auto-boxed parameters, but I'd rather require such methods to explicitly request auto-boxing behavior than allow boxing to occur willy-nilly.